# How to send a 2D array through a socket to a server in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

I have a 2D dynamic array containing integers and strings that I need to send to the server. The array comprises of 100,000 columns. One possibility is to copy the array into a file and send it to the server and the server can parse it. Whereas, the other possibility is to do serialisation. I am doing socket programming for the first time and the solution that I am looking for should be optimal. Considering the size of the array, I dont think converting each element into bytes would be good. Please could you give me a slight hint or guide me on how I should proceed.

Comment: "should be optimal" optimal in what way? Speed? Security? Reliability? Have you tried something? As it stands, the question is way too broad!

Comment: In terms of speed

Comment: Depending on the speed and quality of the network it could be useful to compress the stream. Again, please add some details!

Comment: Actually, the network is secure and we just need to send the 2D array to the server. I am currently doing this project on my local machine which will later on be deployed on to a VM. So, my only concern at the moment is to send the array

Comment: but definitely once we have it running on a VM then our concern will be speed and the channel is secure

Comment: You should edit the question instead of adding comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Serializing the data to bytes for streaming over a socket, or serializing the data to a file, and sending the file is essentially the same thing.  If you serialize to a file you can fall back on an established protocol like FTP, which will be easier for a developer new to sockets.

Again however, realize they're essentially the same problem.  Breaking down a programmatic object into bytes for writing to an output stream.

Edit:

Depending on the content of your strings, using the zip compression algorithm is a good bet.  The more repeated content in your strings, the better compression ratio you'll get.  Here's just an example file format:

- Number of ints to follow. (As you've not given the max ROWS in your 2D array I can't say how many bytes this will take.  We'll assume its 8 bytes.)
- All ints.  This will take 3*NUM_INTS bytes.
- Zip compressed strings, separated by a space.

I'm making a lot of assumptions here because you've not been specific enough in your question, or any replies you've given.

Comment: Now the problem is, what type of file are we talking about?

Comment: That depends on what type of data you have.  What is the range of your integers? Does this file need to be consumed by humans?  How long are your strings? @Shahzaib

Comment: The integers comprise of six digits and the strings are of 10 characters

Comment: So you can store the integers in 3 bytes. There's one speed optimization.  If you can ensure the integers in a contiguous block you can precede the block with the number of integers to follow.  Then the number of strings to follow, then the strings.  I'll give an example in my answer.

Comment: @Shahzaib updated. If you have further questions, please explain precisely what content the 2D array represents, and the maximum dimensions of the 2D array.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.... The array consists of unique numbers(Inverses of number) and unique strings (words) so compression wont be possible. The maximum size of the array is 113,000

Comment: Compression is still definitely possible. It does not matter that the strings are unique because the characters themselves are not. @Shahzaib

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it to json or xml and send that. Is not the most efficient solutions in terms of speed, but is the most portable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use a `DataOutputStream` and wrap it around the socket you are using: `DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOuputStream())`.

You then could just establish your own simple binary protocol like this (it's for an 1D array, but it can be easily extended to work for 2D arrays as well):

```
//first write the amount of elements in the array
dOut.write(array.length());

//now write every element    
for (Object obj : array) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
       dOut.writeByte(0); //0 = Integer
       dOut.writeInt((Integer) obj);
    } else
         if (obj instanceof String) {
             dOut.writeByte(1); //1 = String
             dOut.writeUTF((String) obj); //UTF-8 encoded String
         }
         // ...
}
```

If you want to optimize for data size then you could also use a `GZIPOutputStream` in between the socket's `OutputStream` and your `DataOutputStream` like this: `new DataOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))`. Of course you have to decompress it on server side for this to work.

Comment: So basically, we will parse each and every element of the array and write it to the server. Wont this bring too much of network traffic? In other words, the speed will decrease.

Comment: This is basically what a serialization protocol does. Except for parsing what kind of object it is and wasting a byte for each element to later tell them apart, this is optimal. If you want more speed and less data, then I suggest separating the objects and put them each in different arrays - so Integers go in an int-array and Strings go in a String-array.

Comment: Also the GZIP compression will shape away some of the traffic (in exchange for performance of course). Especially if you have a lot of equal objects in close proximity within your array.